# Reading ZipFile with android DocumentFile

Tags: javascript, android

I want to read a zip file with `java.util.zip.ZipFile` with android `DocumentFile`

**Illustration:**

With Storage Access Framework, I get the uri of a file in the android system and create a Documentfile with it. The document file is a folder that has a zip file "data.zip"

Data.zip has over 80 entries consisting of both text files and media file( >= 8mb <= 20mb). So, zip file is over 932mb.

With the filePAth, I can read an entry directly with the snippet below :

```
zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath);
                ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry(name);
                if (zipEntry != null) {
                    return writeByteArraysToFile(ByteStreams.toByteArray(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)), ext);
                }
```

This works great on devices that does not required Storage access Framework.

For Devices that uses SAF, I am using a DocumentFile and I have reading the content like this :

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(documentFile.getUri());

                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
                ZipEntry entry;
                while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {

                    Log.e("field", entry.getName());
                    if (entry.getName().contains(name)) {
                        File file = PBUtils.writeByteArraysToFile(ByteStreams.toByteArray(zipInputStream), ext);
                        zipInputStream.closeEntry();
                        inputStream.close();
                        zipInputStream.close();
                        bufferedInputStream.close();
                        return file;
                    }
                    zipInputStream.closeEntry();
                }
                inputStream.close();
```

Not This Works, But here's the problem:

1. while iterating through the entries to find a particular entry, it is slow. I debug and find out the time it take to read a media entry causes the delay.

I need solutions on how I can make this faster and need to know if there's any way I can use ZipFile with DocumentFile so I can at least do something like this:

```
zipFile = new ZipFile(documentFileUri);
                ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry(name);
                if (zipEntry != null) {
                    return writeByteArraysToFile(ByteStreams.toByteArray(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)), ext);
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really a bummer - Google is force-feeding us unwanted Scope Storage, but not providing means to work with it where needed. One way to do this:

```
    // mDocFile is a DocumentFile..., you also need a context (activity, service, app...
    String getDocReadableFilePath(DocumentFile mDocFile, Context context) {
        if (mDocFile != null && mDocFile.isFile()) {
            try {
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                        context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(mUri, "r"); // gets FileNotFoundException here, if file we used to have was deleted
                if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
                    int fd = parcelFileDescriptor.detachFd(); // if we want to close in native code
                    return "/proc/self/fd/" + fd;
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    // Now you may use:
    String documentFilePath = getDocReadableFilePath(docFile, context);
    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(documentFilePath);
```

Comment: This gives (Permission denied)

Answer (score 1):

With android `DocumentFile` you have to use `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream` or `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream` instead of `java.util.zip.ZipFile` that can be used with android `context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream()` and `context.getContentResolver().openInputStream()`